# Getting Random Output Using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a database containing more than 100,000 values. The structure looks something like as follows:

> id | countryid | webid | categoryid | title | dateaddedon

If I use basic RAND() considering there are so many ids it won't be able to return a random result. I end up seeing titles of same webid next to each other. I would rather want titles from different webids being displayed. Therefore I figured since there are only 4-5 different values of webid it might be a better option to randomize the output based on this. I am unable to figure out how to define which specific column values should be randomized when using mysql SELECT command.

I am current using following

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE countryid='1' ORDER BY dateaddedon DESC, RAND(3)
```

I am currently using 3 as seed value. I am not sure what kind of impact does seed value have on RAND. I would highly appreciate if someone could explain that too.

Comment: If you specify same seed value every time then you get same results every time!

Comment: Yeh that I know but what I was asking in the last part was if I set seed value to 10 will it have any greater impact on randomization?

Answer (score 0):

If seed value is specified it  produces a repeatable sequence of column values. Unless you require a repeatable value leave it out. Also if you should have the RAND() as the first clause in ORDER.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE countryid='1' ORDER BY RAND(),dateaddedon DESC
```

Comment: This will have same effect as it wont randomize the output based on webid. It will just be random based on id

Comment: As I assume id is unique what is the problem. If you try to force some kind of result based on other criteria you will not have  randomness.

Comment: The issue with keeping id unique is that there are too many entries. I want the webid to alternate at best, if not at least come randomly so that when the data is displayed it shouldn't be that all entries belonging to same webid are displayed next to each other.